# В чем разница между «через X после Y» и «спустя X после Y»?

Tags: выбор-слова, предлоги

> **Через** неделю-другую **,** **после** обсчёта результатов оказалось, что человек не рыбка. [*no dash before negation*]
>
> **Спустя** неделю-другую **,** **после** обсчёта результатов оказалось, что человек не рыбка. [*no dash before negation*]

Я понимаю, что за предлогом «после» следуют какое-то происходящее действие или событие, например, «обсчёта результатов», тогда как фразе, обозначающей какой-то срок, например, «неделю-другую» требуется предлог «через» или «спустя».

Интересно же, чем по смыслу и употреблению «через X после Y» отличается от «спустя X после Y»?

Comment: @Abakan I didn't want to name names, but since your trolling-downvoting tendency seems to be getting out of hand, I point out – what's the point of this unhealthy obsession with points. I see what made you a recent convert to trolling (please don't call me psychic, though), but please exercise your discretion in accordance with SE's policies. SE's voting system doesn't exist for this sort of thing.

Comment: Выражение "спустя" более художественное, чем "через". Первая фраза лучше смотрится в научной статье, а вторая - в научно-популярной.

Answer (score 1):

После обсчёта результатов оказалось, что человек не рыбка. (БЕЗ ТИРЕ!!!)

(когда именно оказалось?) > производится уточнение времени

1) Через неделю-другую

2) Спустя неделю-другую

Я считаю, что именно в данных двух случаях обе конструкции эквивалентны друг другу

Answer (score 1):

Конструкция "...спустя...после..." мне кажется неестественной. 
Обычно "спустя" используется для описания события, которое следовало после события, описанного в предыдущем предложении либо в сложносочинённых предложениях:"Обсчитали результаты.(,a) Неделю-другую спустя оказалось, что человек не рыбка".

Поверхностный поиск по Национальному корпусу русского языка подтверждает моё предположение.